# Duplicating openssl command in BouncyCastle .Net

Tags: c#, openssl, bouncycastle, csr

I'm trying to generate a CSR to use with ApplePay.  We will be running this on a server and generating 1000s of these over time.  I'd prefer to do this in code/memory instead of running the openssl commands directly so the private key will never be on the HHD.

I know these openssl commands work.

```
openssl ecparam -out private.key -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -sha256 -key private.key -nodes -out request.csr -subj '/O=Your Name or Company/C=US'
```

This is my code:

```
// generate the key with a specified curve,
X9ECParameters curve = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
ECDomainParameters ecParam = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H, curve.GetSeed());
ECKeyPairGenerator keyGen = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
keyGen.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecParam, new SecureRandom()));

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPairServer = keyGen.GenerateKeyPair();

var p10builder = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest
(
    "SHA256WITHECDSA",
    new X509Name("O=NAB Test,C=US"),
    keyPairServer.Public,
    null,
    keyPairServer.Private
);

// build string to send to Apple
string csr = CSR_HEADER + "\r\n" + Convert.ToBase64String(p10builder.GetEncoded()) + "\r\n" + CSR_FOOTER;
```

Apple's page accepts the certificate and gives me the response cert for me to pull some info out of.  However when I 'activate' this cert I get 'unknown error'.  Because I'm using BC Apple support refuses to help.  One thing I do notice is that my CSR data about twice as long as the data from OpenSSL.

I think it might be related to -nodes but i'm not sure.

Comment: The Bouncy Castle folks are very helpful. I seems to recall seeing a few similar questions in the past on their mailing list archives. Also see [Apple Push Notification certificates without the Mac Keychain](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/12/apple-push-notification-certificates-without-the-mac-keychain/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was based in how the curve is passed into the key gen.  If you pass a key param all that data ends up in the cert.  If you just use the OID of the curve it doesn't pass all the curve data and this is what Apple was upset about.

DerObjectIdentifier ecParam = new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.10045.3.1.7");